# Build error in visual studio

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

Whenever I build my app that I am making, I get the same error every time "None of the input catalogs contained a matching stickers icon set or app icon set named "AppIcon". In info.plist it is correctly referencing the right app icon file. The app has previously loaded perfectly fine using the exact same assets for the app icon, and this is the first time the issue has become apparent. I have looked at other answers on the site suggesting that I go to build settings and make sure it is building with the right icon set, and it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your iOS project, go to Resource/images.xcassets folder, search for any file named AppIcon...etc, be sure you have selected files for the resolutions you need. In Info.plist/iPhone icons section be sure to select the folder which points to the AppIcon set folder (e.g. images.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset) Next delete bin and obj folders in your iOS project, rebuild the project.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! It removed the issue, however it has caused a new error and warning: Error: The ResolveLibraryProjectImports task failed unexpectedly

Comment: Nevermind! I have fixed the error. Thank you for your quick response and help

Comment: Glad it helped !